# Wix Localization

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have localized all the strings which I added in the project.

But a "Cancel" button in Error dialog in Wix which comes while uninstall is not localized.

Its showing in English. The text in the dialog is localized.This dialog is default wix dialog.
I have added `WixUI_ErrorProgressText` library in wxs file.

Answer (score 1):

got a solution..
by changing Edit Summary Information of msi and change Languages to corresponding language code.
Do this using any patch or programming language like vc++ etc.